# I am promoted but my Manager did not announce it to the team

Tags: software-industry, management, promotion, teamleader

I was recently told by my manager privately that I will lead the software team and asked me to give a software update presentation to the team. I did that and I saw some surprised faces in my team.

For background, I have about 7 in the team and I think 5 out of 7 have a good impression about me. The others don't like me much but do not hate me either. But I am okay with them and trying more to reach to them.
I had a new manager recently and he is not familiar with software.

I have been doing the sw delegation,mentor-ship,training to a small group of specialist teams (3-4) for the past year or so. So, the duties are not totally new except that it's broader than my specialist team.

My questions

1. Is not announcing the team lead directly and asked to present a form of test in the business world?
2. What could be the possible reason that makes the management do it?

My guesses are that they want to know about how the team mates feels before making official announcement.

Comment: SW is software? Or something else?

Comment: I don’t know what SW is but you’re probably overthinking  this. Your manager probably assumed you would tell them yourself during the presentation or that the team would be able to put two and two together when they see you leading the presentation. I wouldn’t worry about it.

Comment: I'm confused... have you received a formal promotions that involved a title change, more pay and an increase in scope? Or was your manager just like, Be the team lead?

Comment: I am confused too.. Manager just told me that you will be the team lead.. nothing else been communicated..

Comment: Sounds like you're being asked to do the job but not being given the job. I think you need to go ask for clarification - is this an actual promotion (with appropriate update to your role in your contract etc) or is the manager just asking you to take on additional responsibility (perhaps with the potential of making it an official promotion in the future). If you assume the former and start telling people this, you could be left in an embarrassing position in the future, especially if the manager ever moves on and a new one comes in with their own ideas.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In a situation like this you pass the onus to the manager to introduce you as team lead. Don't do a presentation without them present and preface your presentation with explaining why you're making it.

Obviously it's too late for this now, so prepare properly for the next one.